# android bluetooth file transfer failure

Tags: java, android, file-transfer, android-networking, rfcomm

here  i am trying to send a file over bluetooth but its not sending any data.
here the main problem is that its not sending or receiving any data over the two devices but they are connected to each other.

Sending code:

```
File myFile = new File(message.toURI());
Double nosofpackets = Math.ceil(((int) myFile.length() )/4096);
System.out.println(nosofpackets);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
byte[] send = new byte[4096];
for(double i = 0; i < nosofpackets; i++)
{
    send = null ;
    a=bis.read(send, 0, send.length);
    Log.d("BluetoothChat", "data packet " + i);
    if(a == -1)
    {
        break;
    }
    mChatService.write(send);
}
```

Receiving code :

```
while((bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "data is there for writing");
    bos.write(buffer);
}
```

Comment: You can refer http://tsicilian.wordpress.com/2012/11/06/bluetooth-data-transfer-with-android/

Comment: @Anu is it possible to send multiple user's at a time using that code for intent setup.. i meant to say that suppose i am trying to send the same file to 4 or more paired devices at one go..is that possible..?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [this library](https://github.com/simonguest/android-btxfr) for sending files and other data between Android devices using Bluetooth (disclaimer: I am the author)